# How to display JSON.stringify to HTML as values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried to fetch data using json, and it worked as I wanted to. But the problem is how can I display it on my page or HTML? what I am getting is `[{"name":"Black wall"},{"name":"Green wall"},{"name":"Gray wall"}]` so How can I make it formal and just display `Black wall, Green wall, Gray wall`. Is there a way to do this?

```
$(function(){
    $(".checkBoxClass").on("click", function() {
        var data = [];
        $("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        var $tr = $(this);
        if ($tr.find(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
            data.push({
            name: $tr.find(".name").text(),
            });
        }
        });
        console.clear();
        var messages = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(messages);
    });
});
```

Comment: Array map() FTW

Comment: @epascarello how can I do it sir, can you give me a guide? thank you I am new to jquery as you can see thanks

Comment: Has nothing to do with jQuery it is just basic JavaScript map() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic array map() with join()

```js
var data = [{"name":"Black wall"},{"name":"Green wall"},{"name":"Gray wall"}];

console.log(data.map(function(obj){ return obj.name; }).join(", "));
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for! thank you very much, I am learning now.

Comment: one last question, how can I call it to my HTML? I have `<span id="name"></span>`

Comment: you set the `text()`

Comment: thank yuo very much sir

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways that you can convert results to your format:

```js
const myResult = [{"name":"Black wall"},{"name":"Green wall"},{"name":"Gray wall"}];

const myItems= myResult.map( (item)=> {
    return item.name;
});

console.log(myItems.join(','))
```